# PostgreSQL: It takes a long time to query many rows

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms, query-optimization, npgsql

I applied PostgreSQL to my project for the first time and now I'm a beginner at the stage of using it. And this is the first time we're dealing with a lot of data.

It takes about 1.5 seconds when I look up many rows (0.5 Million rows). I want to reduce the time required by less than half. I'd like to make sure it's possible. If possible, how can I improve Query or change PostgreSQL settings?

The structure of table.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS table_data_info_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE "public"."table_data_info" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_data_info_id_seq'::regclass),
    "data_id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "tool_id" int4,
    "count_data" int2,
    "type_channel_1" "public"."type_graph",
    "count_channel_1" int2,
    "type_channel_2" "public"."type_graph",
    "count_channel_2" int2,
    "type_sample" "public"."type_sample",
    "revision" int2,
    "decimal_place" int2,
    "date_time" timestamp,
    "event_id" int4,
    "fastening_time" int2,
    "preset" int2,
    "target_torque" int2,
    "torque" int2,
    "speed" int2,
    "angle_1" int2,
    "angle_2" int2,
    "angle_3" int2,
    "screws" int2,
    "error_code" int2,
    "direction" "public"."type_direction",
    "status" "public"."type_status",
    "snug_angle" int2,
    "seating" int2,
    "clamp" int2,
    "prevailing" int2,
    "compensation" int2,
    "unit" "public"."type_unit",
    "barcode" text,
    CONSTRAINT "table_data_info_data_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("data_id") REFERENCES "public"."table_data"("id") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT "table_data_info_tool_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("tool_id") REFERENCES "public"."table_tool"("id") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS table_tool_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE "public"."table_tool" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_tool_id_seq'::regclass),
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    "ip" inet NOT NULL,
    "serial_number" text NOT NULL,
    "type" int2 NOT NULL,
    "model" int2 NOT NULL,
    "version" int2 NOT NULL,
    "register_date" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "disabled" bool DEFAULT false,
    "description" text,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS table_data_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE "public"."table_data" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_data_id_seq'::regclass),
    "tool_id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "date_time" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "status" "public"."type_status",
    CONSTRAINT "table_data_tool_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("tool_id") REFERENCES "public"."table_tool"("id") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Query and Explain plan.

```
SELECT 
   i.data_id, i.tool_id, i.count_data, i.type_channel_1, i.count_channel_1, 
   i.type_channel_2, i.count_channel_2, i.type_sample, i.revision, i.decimal_place,
   i.date_time, i.event_id, i.fastening_time, i.preset, i.target_torque, i.torque,
   i.speed, i.angle_1, i.angle_2, i.angle_3, i.screws, i.error_code, i.direction,
   i.status, i.snug_angle, i.seating, i.clamp, i.prevailing, i.compensation,
   i.unit, i.barcode, t.name
FROM table_data_info as i
INNER JOIN table_tool as t on i.tool_id = t.id
```

```
Hash Join  (cost=4.25..12246.72 rows=415937 width=99) (actual time=0.043..140.230 rows=418372 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (i.tool_id = t.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on table_data_info i  (cost=0.00..11104.37 rows=415937 width=85) (actual time=0.010..17.110 rows=418372 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=3.00..3.00 rows=100 width=18) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=100 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14kB
        ->  Seq Scan on table_tool t  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=100 width=18) (actual time=0.008..0.017 rows=100 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.151 ms
Execution Time: 146.977 ms
```

My system

```
OS : Windows 11 22H2 64bit
Processor : Intel core i7-9700K CPU 3.60GHz
RAM : 16.0GB
SSD : 250.0 GB
PostgreSQL : v15 (lasted version)

Test project environment
Visual studio 2019
C# 7.3
.Net Framwork 4.8
NpgSQL 4.1.8
```

The settings in postgreSQL are the default values that you have not changed since installation.

I made a test program using C# for the test.

```
// connection
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(DbManager.DbString))
{
    // open
    conn.Open();
    // command
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(string.Empty, conn))
    {
        // set query
        cmd.CommandText =
            $@" SELECT 
                    i.data_id, i.tool_id, i.count_data, i.type_channel_1, i.count_channel_1, 
                    i.type_channel_2, i.count_channel_2, i.type_sample, i.revision, i.decimal_place,
                    i.date_time, i.event_id, i.fastening_time, i.preset, i.target_torque, i.torque,
                    i.speed, i.angle_1, i.angle_2, i.angle_3, i.screws, i.error_code, i.direction,
                    i.status, i.snug_angle, i.seating, i.clamp, i.prevailing, i.compensation,
                    i.unit, i.barcode, t.name
                FROM table_data_info i
                INNER JOIN table_tool t on i.tool_id = t.id";
        // debug
        var time = DateTime.Now;
        // execute
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // read
            while (reader.Read())
            {
            }
        }
        // debug
        Debug.WriteLine($@"{(DateTime.Now - time).TotalMilliseconds} ms");
    }

    // close
    conn.Close();
}
```

I measured the time from executing the query through this code to reading all rows.
The result is at least 1100 ms to a maximum of 1500 ms. This time is still within the acceptable range, but if the data exceeds 10 million, it will take time that is no longer acceptable.
There is also a way to limit the number of data that can be viewed, but I want to improve performance before that.

Can you give me a little help?
Thank you.

Comment: Your execution plan shows the query only takes less 150ms not 1500ms. So the difference is network latency/speed plus overhead in your application code.

Comment: A quick back-of-the-envelope calculation puts each record at ~82 bytes + the sizes of type_graph x2, type_sample, type_direction, type_status, type_unit. I've no idea how large those types are (type_graph sounds like it might be large), but let's ballpark the whole thing at 200 bytes. You've got 500,000 rows, so you're reading 95MB in 0.5s, or 190MB/s, which is at the lower end of SSD read speeds? That's ignoring all sorts of other overheads, so it looks like your limit might be disk read speed perhaps? Have you checked your disk utilisation while querying?

Comment: @canton7: according to the execution plan, the average size of a row is 99 bytes. So that makes a total of roughly 40MB. And the time to read that on the server is 150ms (an `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)` could show the actual I/O time of the query if `track_io_timing` was enabled

Comment: Good spot. So that puts you at in the range of HDDs? If OP wants to read 10 million rows of 99 bytes each in 1.5s, that's about 630MB/s, which is above what SATA can offer but in the range of NVMe?

Comment: The point of all these comments? When a query's result set contains a crapton of data, there's no weird SQL voodoo magic that makes it fast to run the query, move the data from SDD / HDD drives, then move it over the network (even the localhost loopback network) to your C# client.

Comment: Your exercise seems pointless. You cannot run a query for all data on small tables and expect that you can guess the performance of a query with a row limit on large tables from that. Always test performance with realistic amounts of data.

Comment: I saw a seq scan on your result of `explain analyze`, which means your tables don't have the required indexes. Looking at your query, I think so you need index for field `tool_id` on table `table_data_info`. Please note that foreign keys this is not indexes.